# Python Writing Csv Files

Tags: python

I'm trying to take data from a csv file, print it out, and create new files.

```
from csv import*
from statistics import*

def read_csv(filename):
csv_data = []
fileObj = open("finals.csv", "r")
    csvContents = reader( fileObj, delimiter =',')
    for row in csvContents:
        csv_data.append(row)
    return csv_data

def print_table (data):
    for i in data:
    print(i)


def get_annual_attendance(data, year):
    total = []
    for i in data:
        if i == year:
            total.append[i]
    return total


def get_statistics(data):
    calculated_statistics = []
    calculated_statistics.append(mean(data))
    calculated_statistics.append(median(data))
    calculated_statistics.append(stdev(data))
    return calculated_statistics

def write_results(data, year, filename):
    attendance = get_annual_attendance(data, year)
    statistics = get_statistics(attendance)
    csvFile = writer(filename, delimiter=',')
    for entry in statistics:
        csvFile.writerow(entry)

def main():
    games = read_csv("finals.csv")
    print_table(games)
    write_results(games, "2009", "2009statistics.txt")
    write_results(games, "2013", "2013statistics.txt")
    write_results(games, "2018", "2018statistics.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

This is the current code I have. When i run it it gives me most of the code i need, but then gives me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/brenn/Documents/python/Homework 
#4/bouillion_brennan_hwf_nbafp.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/brenn/Documents/python/Homework 
#4/bouillion_brennan_hwf_nbafp.py", line 51, in main
    write_results(games, "2009", "2009statistics.txt")
  File "C:/Users/brenn/Documents/python/Homework 
#4/bouillion_brennan_hwf_nbafp.py", line 42, in write_results
    statistics = get_statistics(attendance)
  File "C:/Users/brenn/Documents/python/Homework  
#4/bouillion_brennan_hwf_nbafp.py", line 34, in get_statistics
    calculated_statistics.append(mean(data))
  File "C:\Users\brenn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-
32\lib\statistics.py", line 310, in mean
    raise StatisticsError('mean requires at least one data point')
statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point
```

And i've never seen that kind of error message. Any help is appreciated.[Correct output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYROW.png)

Comment: it looks as if `data` may be empty and that is why it is complaining about needing at least one data point

Comment: that has nothing to do with `csv`. You're feeding `mean` with empty data. It's possible that your csv file has empty rows

Comment: btw `csvFile = writer(filename, delimiter=',')` doesn't work. You have to open the file then pass the handle to `csv.writer` object, not the filename (a problem you'll have later :))

Comment: As an aside, the [PEP8 guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) recommends against using `*` in your imports, rather using `import csv` than `from csv import *` as the latter can clutter and confuse the namespace

Answer (score 0):

You could have an element less than zero in your data which could also throw this error https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html